# ¿Debe de ser «el» o «la» inferior de una página?

Tags: género

A pesar de ser lo más normal escribir *la parte inferior* de una página, entrome la duda si se podía usar apenas *la inferior*.  El DLE no recoge *inferior* como sustantivo propio (la 3.<sup>a</sup> admite uso como sustantivo, pero con ambos géneros).  Buscando en Google, resulta que esta construcción «la inferior de la página» tiene escaso uso especialmente frente a «el inferior de la página».  Qué curioso, ya que no veo a qué se refiere en masculino.  La parte, la sección, el área, la zona, la división, la mayoría de las palabras que se puede concebir como posiblemente el referente son femeninas.

¿Hay alguna forma de explicar el uso en masculino de *inferior* para referir a esa parte de la página?

Comment: supongo que si usamos inferior como sustantivo, el genero debe ser masculino 

sin embargo si lo estamos usando como adjetivo este carecera de genero y poseera el genero de aquello que esta describiendo : 

la (parte) inferior

Comment: No sé si será que hasta principios del siglo XX se decía "lo inferior": "lo inferior de la tierra", "lo inferior del cuerpo", etc. Igual que "lo interior", por ejemplo, pasó a ser "el interior" con la sustantivización del adjetivo, análogamente "lo inferior" pasó a "el inferior".

Comment: @Charlie claro!  Se me olvidó este uso del neutro.  En neutro sí registra en Google muchos usos aunque no tantos como en masculino.

Comment: Pero el neutro es LO y no EL. El masculino es porque cuando hablas de la página, esta tiene lados, lugares, bordes, cantos, márgenes. Cuando referencias al elemento que ya fue nombrado antes y no tienes disponible el "antes" debes inducir que el uso es correcto buscando la inducción lógica, no tratar de romperla. El español es demasiado rico y lleno de palabras para que lo restrinjas con sólo los sustantivos femeninos que conoces.

Comment: @Billeeb pero en la conversación normal, las palabras más comunes para referir a estar parte de la página son femeninas por lo que se supondría que entraría sustantivado en femenino.  Y claro, el neutro es *lo*, e históricamente es la forma más común.  La explicación, por eso, podría nada más el proceso normal de convertir lo neutro en masculino (algo bien documentado, se debe en gran parte por la falta de distinción que hace el castellano entre estos dos géneros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curiosamente, ayer me sorprendí a mí mismo usando "el inferior". Y digo "sorprendí" porque hasta ahora estaba de acuerdo con [la respuesta de Jean Gotopo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23734/13628).

El texto que estaba yo escribiendo era algo así:

> *En **la parte superior** de la página aparece tal cosa, en **el centro** tal otra y en **el inferior** tal otra.*

Tras quedarme un rato mirando lo que acababa de escribir y pensando en por qué lo había escrito así, creo que es por influencia de "el centro": al ser una enumeración de *las* partes, el adjetivo "inferior" debería ir con artículo femenino, pues se refiere a *la (parte) inferior*; pero, **al precederle "el centro", que es un sustantivo, parece como si produjese una influencia sobre el siguiente elemento, como forzando una sustantivación** (¿por coherencia entre elementos correlativos?).

Por contraste, si reescribo la enumeración para usar el adjetivo "central" en vez del sustantivo "centro", entonces lo que me sale naturalmente sí es "la inferior":

> *En **la parte superior** de la página aparece tal cosa, en **la central** tal otra y en **la inferior** tal otra.*

Así, mientras que "inferior" en esta última frase funciona como adjetivo de "parte" y por tanto va en femenino, en el ejemplo de arriba "inferior" no funciona como adjetivo, sino como sustantivo igual que "centro", y por tanto adopta un género propio.

Ignoro si esa podría ser la causa del uso de "el inferior", pero me parece plausible. Quizá alguien con más base lingüística pueda aportar algún comentario.

Answer (score 3):

A lo que estás haciendo referencia es lo que se conoce como **Deixis**, o para ser más claro, una referencia a un elemento que se ha dicho antes, o se dirá despues, o debe inferirse. Ese elemento referenciado puede ausentarse de la frase: "la (parte) inferior" - la inferior. Entonces, no se está tomando a inferior como un sustantivo, sino como un adjetivo que califica a un elemento ya referenciado (anáfora), o por referenciar (catáfora), o también a ser inferido.

Ahora bien, en cuanto al uso masculino, ya colocaste un uso, creo que no te diste cuenta: *el (área) inferior de la página*. Otro uso sería: *el (sector) inferior de la página*.

Nota: Coloco entre paréntesis, los elementos que pueden ser omitidos.

Comment: Nota que *área* es voz femenina.

Comment: Àrea es una palabra que puede denominarse como ambigua en cuanto a uso de dterminantes, y en cuanto a uso de adjetivos. En el español existen ese tiepo de excepciones, tu formalmente dices *el* área, pero cuando colocas adjetivos, los pones en femino: área cuadrad*a*. De igual forma pasa por ejemplo con *agua*, te refieres a *el* agua, pero cuando la calificas, usas feminino: agua *salada*. Ese tipo de excepciones existen y hay que considerarlas.

Comment: Una palabra de género ambiguo sería tilde, que existe y se usa total y equivalentemente sin distinción en masculino y femenino, como por ejemplo *tilde*, *mar* o *azúcar* ...

Comment: ... En contraste, *agua*, *águila*, *área* y otras parecidas son palabras 100% femeninas, pero por razones etimofonéticas se usa el artículo femenino (sí, femenino) *el*, pero vuelve a la forma típica con la introducción de cualquier otra palabra entre artículo y sustantivo (parecida cosa ocurre con el artículo indefinido, pero hay libre variación *un~una* en aquellas situaciones). Su feminidad se puede probar por pronombres átonos directos: *¿Quieres el agua? Sí, **la** quiero.*

Answer (score 0):

He investigado más al respecto, y lo que pasa en este caso, es lo que se llama Eufonía, y en oposición a la cacofonía, se aplica en la lengua a la sonoridad de las palabras que los hablantes consideran agradable. En este caso, para evitar el hiato fonético que se produciría al decir "la area" o "la agua" por ello entonces, se dice "el área" y "el agua" para que suene bien (eufonía).

Comment: La Eufonía aplica entonces de esta manera: el artículo "el" se aplica los femeninos que comienzan por «a» tónica, en lugar de «la», para evitar el hiato que resultaría de la concurrencia de dos aes: «el alma», «el ama»